# How to use wildcard in if condition csh script

Tags: shell, csh

I have the following csh script to check if a file exists with an extension sts. If it exists then using foreach statement zip all the sts files. But my if condition is not working with wildcard `*`. Any help?

```
#! /bin/csh

if (-e "m*.sts") then
 foreach file (m*.sts)
  bzip2 $file
 end
endif
```

I could remove the if statement altogether as the foreach part of my script works well but if my files are already zipped then the lines in my script after these lines don't work as the foreach has no match. 
I have tried the if statement with !-e and without using quotes but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

The test `-e "m*.sts"` checks if there is a file named `m*.sts` in the current folder.

You want to try force the filename expansion, with the nonomatch. Otherwise, commands which do not match any file will fail.

```
set nonomatch=1
FLIST=( m*.sts )
usnet nonomatch
if (-e "$FLIST") then
 foreach file ($FLIST)
  bzip2 $file
 end
endif
```